# Filter the output of locate not to show the Duplicates in rsnapshot

Tags: grep, rsnapshot

When I use locate on my server and the result is in my `rsnapshot`  backup then I get all those duplicates.

I could use grep to filter out all rsnapshot files:

```
locate something_in_backup | grep -v /var/cache/rsnapshot
```

but then I would miss files in the backup that are coming from other servers.

How could I filter the output to show only results from the `rsnapshot/daily.0/` folder?

Comment: Best way would be to find the scripts that build the locate database and add the directories you want to filter to the blacklist in the script.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't want that, because, I need all old backupped files in the locate database also

Comment: If you don't want to prune the database, then `grep -v` is your friend.  Locate can do some pattern matching, but it doesn't have a blacklist feature.  Although it can filter by permissions, so you could make the directories unsearchable to some users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions in the grep command:

```
locate something_in_backup | grep -v 'rsnapshot/\(hourly.[1-5]\|daily\|weekly\|monthly\)'
```

or if you don't backup hourly:

```
locate something_in_backup | grep -v 'rsnapshot/\(daily.[1-7]\|weekly\|monthly\)'
```

*note the right escaping of pipe and brackets*